# Wordpress- Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, cpanel

Just did a fresh install of Wordpress to a new subdomain through CPanel and am getting the message: "Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress."

phpinfo.php is telling me that I'm running PHP version 7.0.33. Updated to Wordpress 5.5.3 ( via https://wordpress.org/download/) just to be safe, but I'm still getting this message. All other resources seem to say that it's a problem with older versions of Wordpress or PHP, but both are up to date, so I'm not sure what exactly the problem is stemming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this working via these steps:
https://www.hostgator.com/help/article/php-configuration-plugin#option2

I had to do the very last step- edit the .htaccess outside the website root.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add the extensions for the PHP through the cPanel:

[image]

[image]

In the PHP Selector, there should be extensions that you can enable or disable.

Comment: It looks like PHP Selector has been discontinued (at leastvia my hostgator Cpanel). I did look into a it and found these steps:
https://www.hostgator.com/help/article/php-configuration-plugin#option2

And got it working! I had to do the very last step- edit the .htaccess outside the website root.

Comment: Usually, cPanel has some kind of tabs where you can select extensions for PHP, I know they updated this through the years. Glad you got it working  